# Strike out and unstrikeout in ListItem of a list view

Tags: java, android, android-listview

I have a little functionality to strike out and unstrike out a list view when a list item is clicked. My code goes Here:

```
public void markComplete(View v)
 {
     Button b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Completeit);
     Button b2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.InCompleted);


     try{
         TextView tv =  (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewx);
     tv.setPaintFlags(tv.getPaintFlags() | Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG);
     }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

     b1.setVisibility(-1);
     b2.setVisibility(1);

 }

 public void markInComplete(View v)
 {
     Button b1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Completeit);
     Button b2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.InCompleted);


     try{
         TextView tv =  (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewx);
         tv.setPaintFlags( tv.getPaintFlags() & (~ Paint.STRIKE_THRU_TEXT_FLAG));
     }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}
     b1.setVisibility(1);
     b2.setVisibility(-1);
 }
```

I have two buttons for checking and unchecking the list item.It works for the first list item alone. If i try to click 2nd list item, the striking & unstriking is done only on 1st item. Any help is appreciated and Thanks in advance

Comment: are these buttons in each listview row?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your findViewById call is going to return the first element in your view that it finds.  If you have multiple, then this is going to be a problem.  It will always find the first table cell.  The solution here is to save your buttons, and treat each cell as a separate view.

Comment: Inflate your layout for each cell into a different view, and then you can use findById for that subview.  Good luck!